# How do I get the client's IP Address in a Server.Resources function with the Delphi MARS REST API Library?

Tags: delphi, ip-address

This question was asked on [Delphi-PRAXIS](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2158-how-do-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-serverresources-function/) many years ago, but the method described in that question doesn't work anymore and is based on a very old version of [MARS](https://github.com/andrea-magni/MARS).

Basically exactly what the person posted and is asking, is what I am asking. Here's his code:

```
  [Path('projectX')]
  TProjectXServicesResource = class
  protected
  public
    [GET, Produces(TMediaType.TEXT_HTML)]
    function xHome([QueryParam] lang : String) : String;

    [POST, Consumes(TMediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Produces(TMediaType.TEXT_HTML)]
    function xAction([FormParams] AParams: TArray<TFormParam>): String;
  end;

function TProjectXServicesResource.xHome([QueryParam] lang : String) : String;
begin
  // Need access to the client's IP here
end;

function TProjectXServicesResource.xAction([FormParams] AParams: TArray<TFormParam>) : String;
begin
  // Need access to the client's IP here
end;
```

I need to know what the IP Address is within the endpoint functions (`xHome` and `xAction`).

`TWebRequest` doesn't seem to exist in MARS anymore. Lots have changed in MARS.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to find, but basically, there's a new interface called `IMARSRequest` from the `MARS.Core.RequestAndResponse.Interfaces` unit that you can use for this.

It works very similar to the old `TWebRequest`.

Using the code below by adding `[Context] MarsRequest: IMARSRequest;` to the `protected` field, you can access `marsRequest.GetRemoteIP` from any of your class functions such as from `xHome` and `xAction`:

```
  [Path('projectX')]
  TProjectXServicesResource = class
  protected
    [Context] marsRequest: IMARSRequest;
  public
    [GET, Produces(TMediaType.TEXT_HTML)]
    function xHome([QueryParam] lang : String) : String;

    [POST, Consumes(TMediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Produces(TMediaType.TEXT_HTML)]
    function xAction([FormParams] AParams: TArray<TFormParam>): String;
  end;

function TProjectXServicesResource.xHome([QueryParam] lang : String) : String;
begin
  ShowMessage(marsRequest.GetRemoteIP);
end;

function TProjectXServicesResource.xAction([FormParams] AParams: TArray<TFormParam>) : String;
begin
  ShowMessage(marsRequest.GetRemoteIP);
end;
```

---

For some added info, you can also use it for an individual endpoint instead of everyone in the class. You can add it as a parameter in the function such as this short code sample here:

```
type
  [Path('helloworld')]
  THelloWorldResource = class
  protected
  public
    [GET, Path('ip_address'), Produces(TMediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)]
    function SayIPAddress([Context] MarsRequest: IMARSRequest): string;
  end;

implementation

uses
  MARS.Core.Registry;

{ THelloWorldResource }

function THelloWorldResource.SayIPAddress([Context] MarsRequest: IMARSRequest): string;
begin
  var RemoteIP := MarsRequest.GetRemoteIP;
  Result := 'Hello, your Remote IP is ' + RemoteIP;
end;
```